# Identify and output first and last records by group

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, worksheet-function, vba

I have over 2 million records/rows of data to analyze. Each row of data has a task identifier in Column A that changes only when a new task begins.  An individual task can have any number of records (rows in Excel).  The rows for the same task are always in chronological order, oldest to newest.

My thinking is to cycle through the unique task identifiers in col A to determine the rows that correspond with each task. Once I have determined the first and last row for each, calculate the AGE of the task by subtracting the date in col B of the FIRST row of data from the date in col C of the LAST row for that task.

The unique identifier, the begin date, the end date and the elapsed time for each task should be output to another sheet in the workbook.

How might I achieve this?

Comment: Seems like a nested `Do Until` loop or other similar structure. It is not possible to help you without seeing example of your code and your data.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See also [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: With 2 million records, you will have a minimum of two worksheets. Make sure you look on all worksheets for similar tasks in order to get an accurate first and last entry for each task. Too bad about your previous efforts but typically, code is easier to rewrite than write so I'm looking forward to seeing examples of your previous effort(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If able to sort by date within task and to ensure that any subsequent sheet starts at a new task and the last ColumnB and ColumnC values on each sheet are repeated in the row immediately below, a formula might suit:

```
=IF(A1<>A2,A1&"|"&VLOOKUP(A1,A:B,2,0)&"|"&C1&"|"&B2-VLOOKUP(A1,A:B,2,0),"")
```

with the columns where the formula output is evident filtered to exclude blanks, the content copied to another sheet and parsed with Text to Columns, pipe delimited and suitable formatting.